# command "mvn package" fails with status 137

Tags: java, gwt, maven

Packaging GWT project using "mvn package" fails and I have the following ouput:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [apt:process {execution: default}]
[INFO] [aspectj:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [aspectj:test-compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] [gwt:compile {execution: gwtcompile}]
[INFO] Compiling module com.MyProject
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Command [[
/bin/sh -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx512M -classpath /home/projects/MyProject/trunk/src/main/java:/home/projects/MyProject/trunk/target/generated-sources/java:/home/projects/MyProject/trunk/src/main/aspect:/home/projects/MyProject/trunk/src/main/resources:/home/projects/MyProject/trunk/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes:/root/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.1/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.6.1/jul-to-slf4j-1.6.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.11.M1/aspectjrt-1.6.11.M1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.6.11.M1/aspectjweaver-1.6.11.M1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/net/sf/flexjson/flexjson/2.0/flexjson-2.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.3.148/h2-1.3.148.jar:/root/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.13/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.0.Final/hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.1/commons-collections-3.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.2.0.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.6.0.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.0.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javassist/javassist/3.12.0.GA/javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.1.0.Final/hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/root/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib-nodep/2.2/cglib-nodep-2.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-pool/commons-pool/1.5.4/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/1.3/commons-dbcp-1.3.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/webflow/spring-js-resources/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-js-resources-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/2.0/commons-digester-2.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.1/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/el/el-api/1.0/el-api-1.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/1.6/joda-time-1.6.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.3.0/gwt-user-2.3.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.5/jersey-client-1.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.5/jersey-core-1.5.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar:/home/projects/MyProject/trunk/lib/gwt-incubator.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/inject/gin/1.5.0/gin-1.5.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-assistedinject/3.0/guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/mysema/querydsl/querydsl-apt/2.1.2/querydsl-apt-2.1.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/mysema/querydsl/querydsl-core/2.1.2/querydsl-core-2.1.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/collections/collections-generic/4.01/collections-generic-4.01.jar:/root/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/mysema/commons/mysema-commons-lang/0.2.1/mysema-commons-lang-0.2.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/mysema/codegen/codegen/0.3.1/codegen-0.3.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.2/jsr305-1.3.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/findbugs/annotations/1.3.2/annotations-1.3.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/mysema/querydsl/querydsl-jpa/2.1.2/querydsl-jpa-2.1.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/2.2/cglib-2.2.jar:/root/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar:/root/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.4/mail-1.4.4.jar:/root/.m2/repository/org/mindrot/jbcrypt/0.3m/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.3.0/gwt-user-2.3.0.jar:/root/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.3.0/gwt-dev-2.3.0.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -gen /home/projects/MyProject/trunk/target/.generated -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war /home/projects/MyProject/trunk/target/MyProject-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT -localWorkers 1 com.MyProject
]] failed with status 137}
```

- Machine is Debian 6.0
- java version "1.6.0_24", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
- maven compiler plugin excerpt from pom.xml:
  1.6
  1.6

Has anyone faced the same problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try running with the -X Maven flag to turn debug output on, that might give you/us some more troubleshooting angles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'killed' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189522/what-does-killed-mean)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding a swap file to the system (there was had no swap at all).

For more details about the reason of that problem look [here](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/JIRA-JENKINS-12035-Job-killed-before-the-end-td4171048.html) .

This is the key fragment:

> In that case the problem was the linux kernel running out of virtual
>   memory. The kernel OOM (out of memory) killer then stepped in and
>   killed the most (un)deserving victim/runaway process which happened to
>   be the GWT/maven build process.
>
> To determine if that is the case you can use the {{dmesg}} command
>   from a linux shell. Somewhere towards the end of the output there will
>   be a line similar to
>
> {code}  Out of memory: kill process 946 (daemon) score 1073527 or a
>   child  {code}
>
> For reference the status code 137 (128 + 9) typically means (can
>   differ between flavours of unix). That the process was terminated by
>   receipt of a signal. In this case signal 9 which is SIGKILL and
>   unblockable kill.
>
> If this is the case the underlying machine/OS needs more virtual
>   memory. This can be added by either adding physical memory or swap
>   space as appropriate.

Comment: +1, the notes on dmesg helped me figure out an issue with a JVM task, under Hadoop, getting killed without any specific reason. Also, learned a bit more about the status code numbers' relevance :). Thanks

Comment: I don't think that the Xmx option helps, since then the JVM would notice the lack of memory and exit with a different error. When the kernel kills a process there must be a real lack of memory.

Comment: Indeed with `dmesg` you can see the exact reason that your process has been killed (by sending it a signal) by the OS! Just run it after your crash, and you will see the exact reason with some additional detail as long as you knew your process id.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I found that the problem was too much memory being allocated, not too little.

When running the job on a machine with 2GB of memory and setting the max heap size to 2GB, the build eventually failed with status 137. However when setting the job to 1GB maximum (e.g. `-Xmx1g -Xms512m`), the build succeeded.

This kind of makes sense, because the JVM will freely increase its memory up to the maximum heap size, but if there's not enough real memory, the OS will kill the process. However, if you reduce the max heap size, the JVM won't try to increase its memory so highly, so the OS won't worry about it enough to kill it.

Furthermore, I was using GWT which forks a separate process for compilation, and the arguments have to be specified as an `extraJvmArgs` element within `gwt-maven-plugin` configuration, not in `MAVEN_OPTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Try another version (or a fresh installation) of JDK/JRE. It looks like java executable is crashing while running GWT compiler. You can also try to compile it another machine to confirm that the problem is with the JDK/JRE installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my system admin found a number of hung processes on the Bamboo server. Clearing those processes resolved the issue. It may not be anything directly to do with your own build.