# grails test-app return code 137

Tags: grails

I'm running grails test-app on a CI server (bamboo). And I'm getting this message:

> Failing task since return code of [/opt/grails-2.4.4/bin/grails test-app unit: integration: -non-interactive] was 137 while expected 0

What specific error does 137 means?

Btw, the result of the test-app was successful.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting answer from user @centic from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801783/resolving-java-result-137/):

Exit codes above 127 typically mean the process was stopped because of a [Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal).

The exit code 137 then resolves to 128 + 9, whereas Signal 9 is SIGKILL, i.e. the process was forcefully killed. This can among others be a "kill -9 " command. However in your case this could be an out of memory condition on the operating system, which causes a functionality called "OOM Killer" to stop the process which is using up most of the memory in order to keep the OS itself stable even in such a condition.