# Script returns "Killed"

Tags: python

I have this rather simple script which generates 1000000000 (nine zeroes) numbers and then store in a file the generated numbers a how many times they were generated.

```
import random
import csv

dic = {}

for i in range(0, 1000000000):
    n = random.randint(0, 99999)
    if n in dic:
        dic[n] += 1
    else:
        dic[n] = 1
writer = csv.writer(open('output', 'w'))
for key, value in dic.iteritems():
    writer.writerow([key, value])
writer.close()
```

The script is exiting with a `Killed` message. According to this question [What does 'killed' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189522/what-does-killed-mean), using `dic.iteritems()` should be enough for preventing such issue, but that's not the case.

So how could I proceed to accomplish such task?

Comment: That dictionary would like about 3GB of memory if it was an array. Do you have that much RAM?

Comment: @RishavKundu - "if it was an array" ... but it is a dictionary

Comment: @cricket_007 dictionaries take up more space than arrays.

Comment: I have 12GB RAM, actually 11GB free

Comment: @RishavKundu The dict has only 100000 entries.

Comment: Use `xrange` rather than `range`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like your problem is the dict. Your problem is here:

```
for i in range(0, 1000000000):
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

On Python 2, that's a list 1000000000 items long, more than your system can handle. You want `xrange`, not `range`. `xrange` generates numbers on demand. (On Python 3, `range` does what `xrange` used to and `xrange` is gone.)

Oh, and if you think 11 GB should be enough for that list: not in Python. Try `sys.getsizeof(0)` to see how many bytes an int takes.

Comment: Still  though, assuming 8 bytes a number, that comes to about 7gb, which doesn’t explain the killed status.

Comment: @RishavKundu: I was actually just about to add something about that to the answer.

Comment: according to your edit, that `range` would be around 22GB.. xD using `xrange` now, still it hasn't finished but it has no crashed either