# Error on Pycharm signal 9: SIGKILL in Mac

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm running a program in Pycharm on Mac I keep getting this error : 'Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)' which stops my code from running.

does anyone know how to avoid this ? letting the program continue running ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process finished with exit code 137 in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268156/process-finished-with-exit-code-137-in-pycharm)

Comment: What does the program do? Does your machine have enough memory to run it?

Comment: @abc I know the issue is about my pc memory but i'm looking for a solution so your suggestion isn't working.

Comment: @Gogo78 without providing essential details like what your code does, or running a memory profiler and show from where the high memory consumption comes, it's hard to provide a universal answer.

Comment: @Gogo78 abc's link provides two possible explanations: 1. you killed the process yourself (unlikely as you would know about that) and 2. the process demanded more memory than your machine (or operating system) can provide. You youself say that you don't have enough memory, so how can anyone help you reducing memory usage without any information about your system, your process or anything else? Here is your answer: Use less or buy more memory.