# How to efficiently concatenate Numpy Array based on position conditioning?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, if-statement

The objective is to concatenate  a Numpy Array according to a set of position. However, I am curious whether the `concatenate` and  step as shown in the code below can be optimized further without the need of `for loop` and if-`else statement`?

```
tot_length=0.2 implementation
steps=0.1
start_val=0
repeat_perm=3 
list_no =np.arange(start_val, tot_length, steps)
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(*[list_no for _ in range(3)], sparse=True)
ix = np.array(((x>=y) & (y>=z)).nonzero()).T
final_opt=list_no[ix]
final_opt[:,[0, 1]] = final_opt[:,[1, 0]] 
all_result=itertools.product(range(0,ix.shape[1]), repeat=repeat_perm)

for num, num_pair in enumerate(all_result, start=1):
    for num_x, num_pair_x in enumerate ( num_pair, start=0 ):
        if (num == 1) &(num_x==0) :
            cont_arry = final_opt [num_pair_x, :]
        else:
            cont_arry= np.concatenate((cont_arry, final_opt  [num_pair_x, :]), axis=0)

final_arr =np.reshape(cont_arry, (-1, 9))

print(final_arr)
```

Output of size `(27, 9)`, but only partial are shown below

```
 [[0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
     [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.  0. ]
     [0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.1 0. ]
     [0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
     [0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.  0.  0.1 0.  0. ]
     [0.  0.  0.  0.1 0.  0.  0.1 0.1 0. ]
     [0.1 0.1 0.  0.1 0.1 0.  0.1 0.1 0. ]]
```

Just some heads up,the `cont_arry` will be `vectorised multiply` with a `1D` array of similar length with the `cont_arry`. Knowing this, is there a way to avoid from storing the result of concatenation  on memory or what not to minimise potential memory issue since in actual application, the worst possible parameter setting is as below

```
tot_length=200 
steps=0.1
start_val=0
repeat_perm=1200
```

Comment: As a general rule, repeated `concatenate` (in a loop) is not a good idea.  It makes a new array each time, with a full copy.  Either assign values to a predefined array, or use list append.

Comment: HI @hpaulj, can you kindly explain more or refer to good reading material about your suggestion `predefined array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concatenate loop can be replaced with:

```
alist = []
for num, num_pair in enumerate(all_result, start=1):
    for num_x, num_pair_x in enumerate ( num_pair, start=0 ):
        alist.append( final_opt  [num_pair_x, :]))
arr = np.array(alist)
# arr = np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)
# arr = np.vstack(alist)
```

There may be some details in this that I didn't catch.  I haven't tried to test it.  List append is much faster than concatenate, especially when done repeatedly.
`concatenate` is most efficient when give a whole list of arrays to join.

Better yet, don't iterate at all; instead make use of whole-array math and indexing.  But I haven't tried to master your code, so won't suggest how to do that.