# Is there a way (step by step) how to setup PyCharm on M1 Mac?

Tags: pycharm, apple-m1

Is there a way (step by step) how to setup PyCharm on M1 Mac? I am looking for some step by step how to get over the interpreter errors. Also there is an error message happening in my simple Hello world print.

> "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The [Mac versions](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac) should work regardless of the architecture. Please edit the question to include details and clarity such as an example of the errors you are getting. Also this kind of question is better suited to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your error message gives [several results on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpycharm%5d%20Process%20finished%20with%20exit%20code%20137) the highest voted one [is this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43268156) which seems to indicate indirect causes for the problem, meaning that possibly your Python-PyCharm installation is in fact working.

Comment: The top answer with the most votes indicates Mac might have closed the connection of your debugger, maybe due to lack of memory or maybe your security software...Try diagnosing using the solutions in those answers, if it still doesn't work edit the question stating what you have tried.

Comment: I will try, however it looks like some deeper issue on M1 macs for now. As eve adding some parts of code did not solve the issue. I will dig in the Jetbrains documentation and will update.

Comment: Well it looks like a problem with Pycharm interpreter configuration. As other IDEs (like Thony or Wing101 works fine with the code. During the debugging it is actually refering to commands like print, that they are unresolved reference. While in other IDEs I can run the code fine.

Comment: OK problem solved this way  .... 1) Restore default settings of IDE 2) Let Pycharm install your interpreter (it will download latest python etc.) 3) Run the code. For some reason every interpreter must be set for specific file but it works. I think the problem was in my in  manual configuration of the intepreter.

Comment: You should self-answer the question and accept the answer. It will be useful for future readers going through the same problem. In cases like this it's also a good bet to get up votes because readers tend to vote on what solves their problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK problem solved this way .... 1) Restore default settings of IDE 2) Let Pycharm install your interpreter (it will download latest python etc.) 3) Run the code. For some reason every interpreter must be set for specific file but it works. I think the problem was in my in manual configuration of the intepreter. –

Answer (score 0):

It is now available for m1 chip download it from here
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=mac
Select m1 chip in drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I found that on an M1 Mac even with the native install I would still get the same error during the initial "Learn Pycharm - Activity 1" - I managed to fix this by replacing the Python interpreter in the project settings (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter)).