# Django killed suddenly after runserver on M1

Tags: python, django, pip, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have couple of project on Django and after hi runserver terminal shows :

```
[1]    23857 killed     python3 manage.py runserver
```

I had update all library for working on Apple M1 and everything was good.
after couple of day I tried to run and everything is crushed.
my requirments.txt is :

```
boto3==1.15.6
botocore==1.18.6
Django==3.1.1
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
django-debug-toolbar==3.1.1
django-storages==1.10.1
django-summernote==0.8.11.6
docutils==0.16
gunicorn==20.0.4
jmespath==0.10.0
Pillow==8.1.0
pipupgrade==1.7.4
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.15.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.10
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

python3 version is 3.9.1

and when I run the code in PyCharm shows:

```
/Users/username/python/myProject/.venv/bin/python3.9 /Users/username/python/myProject/myApp/manage.py runserver 8000
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

I read maybe the problem of SIGKILL is about memory but half of my ram is free
~5GIG used
3GIG free

Comment: It could be a permission issue (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504880/8439435))

Comment: did "sudo chmod 777 *" and no success

Comment: Did you try to reboot your computer ?

Comment: yeah, I did ,no success .
I tested on another Intel macbook and it works , I dont know what the hell is going on in M1 Chip

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is it the same problem like this - [Python/pip process are killed in virtualenv (Apple M1 chip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66860350/python-pip-process-are-killed-in-virtualenv-apple-m1-chip/66860351#66860351). Maybe you can try the steps and use x86_64 mode shell to execute django.