# Python/pip process are killed in virtualenv (Apple M1 chip)

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, apple-m1

When I execute pip or python in MacBook M1 chip virtualenv, the process always terminates immediately with message like:

```
[1]    29116 killed     pip
```

or

```
[1]    29141 killed     python
```

Python and pip in M1 MacBook native environment run fine.

Only in the virtualenv they don't work.

Comment: For searchability: on my Mac M1 using Bash the error message is slightly different: `Killed: 9`.

Comment: This problem exists only for Python 2. For Python 3 virtualenvs work perfectly fine on Macs with Apple M1 chip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research, I find out it is related with "x86_64" and "arm 64" architecture. To solve the problem, you have to run virtualenv python/pip in x86_64 mode.

Steps:

1. **Disable SIP**: reboot MacBook in Recover Mode. Open `Utilities > Terminal` enter `csrutil disable`. ref: [Disabling and Enabling System Integrity Protection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection)
2. **Run SHELL as x86_64 mode**: enter `arch -x86_64 $SHELL` in Terminal.
3. **Execute python/pip successfully**

After that, I enable SIP again and keep using `arch -x86_64 $SHELL` every time. It will execute python/pip in virtualenv succesfully.

To save my time, I add an alias in my **.zshrc**:

> alias x86="arch -x86_64 $SHELL"

Now if I need execute some process in x86_64 mode, I just type `x86` to open the x86_64 shell.

Note: MxJ24 on github provides this solution and lists some useful scripts for python/django/brew: https://gist.github.com/MxJ24/e1386c9012f533cfbedfed5114da3e60

Comment: Not sure why, but just setting the alias worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Python 2 virtualenvs are just not working on Macs with Apple Silicon chip as of now. See https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/2024 for more information.

The workarounds involving disabling System Integrity Protection and using x86_64 emulation may be unsafe and inefficient and I suggest ***against*** following them.

The best solution would obviously be to switch/migrate/upgrade to **Python 3**, for which virtualenv works like a charm.

If that's not a viable option, then I would consider using **Docker instead of virtualenv**. `python:2` Docker image has the latest Python 2.7.18 version and is available on aarch64 architecture, so it will run without x86_64 emulation. I don't know your use case, but I am using IntelliJ IDEA/PyCharm and it supports using Docker as the SDK, so after a one-time setup it's seamless.

Answer (score 0):

use SHELL as x86_64 mode by executing arch -x86_64 $SHELL this comand in the terminal

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).