# My Programm cannot find the command "print" on python

Tags: python, printing

This is my first time programming and I am trying to learn but while trying to run my program which is :

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("hello world")
```

It answers me that:

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

Cause the executed cannot find the command "print".
Could you please help me thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Process finished with exit code 137 in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268156/process-finished-with-exit-code-137-in-pycharm)

Comment: How are you attempting to run this code?

Comment: What makes you think it can't find the command `print`? The error message doesn't say anything about that, it says the process was killed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.