# Function not working in R even though I installed python dependency

Tags: python, r

I am using this function called phate in R.

https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/phate/latest/phate.pdf

I downloaded phate in R and python through pip install as mentioned in document above.

I am still getting the following error in R:

```
Error in python_config(python_version, required_module, python_versions) : 
  Error 137 occurred running /Users/abhaykanodia/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/python
```

Comment: It's not running out of memory is it? Just basing this on the error code, which I found a post about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268156/process-finished-with-exit-code-137-in-pycharm). I assume you already searched for the error code but you didn't actually mention if you tried or searched anything at all before posting here.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. Yes I looked into my memory usage and it shows only 4% utilization. I could not find anything helpful with the first line of the error.

Comment: Are all the permissions for that python path correct, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504880/6273251) talks about?