# How to optimize this github action workflow to remove timeout and failures

Tags: deployment, nestjs, github-actions, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy NestJS project on a digital ocean droplet. It has a configuration of 25GB SSD and 2GB RAM but I am still facing issues like timeout even just on `npm i` with SSH and if I run `npm run build` command with SSH digital ocean server it crashed due to NodeJS out of memory. I am not sure is something wrong with my droplet or why it taking so much time. My project has just 5 endpoints nothing very complex for now

What improvement I can do in my GitHub action workflow also if somehow I can avoid downtime of service and reduce deployment time?

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'

      - run: npm i

      - run: npm run build

      - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.7
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          script: |
            if [ -d "/opt/nodejs_project" ]; then rm -Rf /opt/nodejs_project; fi
            mkdir /opt/nodejs_project 
            cp ~/secret/.env.prod /opt/nodejs_project/
            cp ~/secret/db.cert /opt/nodejs_project/

      - name: Copy dist to VPS
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          # Selecting all folders except "node_modules"
          source: '.,!node_modules'
          # The path is based on the directory where the user logged into the server starts
          target: '/opt/nodejs_project'

      - name: executing remote ssh commands using password
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.7
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          script: |
            chown -R root /opt/nodejs_project
            cd /opt/nodejs_project
            npm i --production
            pm2 restart all
```

Comment: Isn't that `ubuntu-20.04` GHA-hosted runner in your workflow where you are running `npm i` and `npm run build` commands? But, you're saying that these run on DO's droplet.

Comment: This looks similar to your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75516010/github-actions-workflow-throws-error-137-when-installing-dependencies

Comment: @Azeem I put it here because when i tried on DO's droplet using self hosted runner it failed so its sort of hack i did here

Comment: @jessehouwing yes it's there I missed in copy pasting script here, updated thanks

Comment: That's actually perfect. The build is on the GHA-hosted runner and then you only deploy the built artifacts to your DO's droplet. With this approach, what is the issue that you're facing now? You might want to edit and update your question according to this scenario.

Comment: @Azeem sometimes this command `npm i --production` never completes like take 8 minutes and then timeout

Comment: Have you observed the behavior (RAM and CPU utilization) on the droplet when this happens?

Comment: yes CPU usage reaches 51% , not sure about the ram

Comment: CPU usage is fine but do you observe any process killed when your workflow timeouts?